# Reproducing nested loops using Map?

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

I keep producing bits of code like the following:

```
stuff = Module[
    {curTarget = #},
    getRowsForUserAndTarget[u, #, curTarget] & /@ validUsers
] & /@ allTargets;
```

Basically, I'm iterating through all the targets and all the users.  Using a For loop it would look something like this (in python):

```
res = []
for user in validUsers:
    for curTarget in allTargets:
        res.append(getRowsForUserAndTarget[u, user, curTarget])
```

It seems like I should be able to do this succinctly in map notation using something like:

```
getRowsForUserAndTarget[#userthing, #targetthing]& /@ validUsers /@ validTargets
```

but I don't know how to keep the mapped arguments from interfering with each other, or how to reference which one I mean; and I'm a little hazy about the order of iteration (validUsers would go first, then validTargets?)

Can someone set me straight?  This would seem like a common pattern that I am abusing with my Module[] solution...

Comment: Plus you could use `Function[{user, target}, getRowsForUserAndTarget[user, target]]` if you want to give your arguments names instead of `#`.

Comment: Can I just say how happy I am with the Mathematica community?  Such fast, friendly, thoughtful answers.  Just the responses to this one question have taught me a great deal.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
l1 = {a, b, c};
l2 = {aa, bb, cc};
sth[#1, #2] & @@@ Tuples[{l1, l2}]
```

> ```
> {sth[a, aa], sth[a, bb], sth[a, cc], sth[b, aa], sth[b, bb], 
>  sth[b, cc], sth[c, aa], sth[c, bb], sth[c, cc]}
> ```

Comment: For this example, `Tuples[sth[{a, b, c}, {aa, bb, cc}]]` works as well.

Answer (score 9):

A couple of other options:

```
allTargets = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
validUsers = {1, 2, 3};

Table[getRowsForUserAndTarget[u, j, i], {i, allTargets}, {j, validUsers}]

Outer[getRowsForUserAndTarget[u, #2, #] &, allTargets, validUsers, 1]
```

Both of these methods produce nested lists separating output elements for each `validUsers` element, whereas `Tuples` produces a flattened list.  This can be either advantagous or problematic.  You can flatten one level using `Join @@` e.g. `Join @@ Table`

Comment: How badly does it hurt to type out `getRowsForUserAndTarget`... twice? ;)

Comment: @R.M in Firefox I can select and Ctrl-drag to copy text in the edit box.  Manually typing `{"a", "b", "c", "d"}` took longer.

Comment: `Table` approach is very useful and makes very clear code. I use to recomend its usage too. The only detail to take into account is that sometimes you need to `Flatten` the output.

Comment: @FJRA if one wants the flat list produced by `Tuples` this is also an issue with `Outer`.  I usually use `Join @@` if as in this case there is a single level to flatten.